# Digital Footprint Law

Tags: cryptography

Can anyone help me with the name of the digital footprint law? All I know is that it is named after its discoverer much like Moore's Law is. This is a computer science law that states for the purposes of encryption that all operations on a computer can be reversed which means that in theory all codes can be cracked. I had this information but errantly lost it. I could be mistaken but I think I first learned of this law in the Jeffery Deaver novel, "The Blue Nowhere" or perhaps the Dan Brown novel, "Digital Fortress". I know those aren't exactly academic textbooks but that may help jog someone's memory.

Comment: I'm not sure that such a thing exists because it's not true, not all operations are reversible.  `0xF >> 1 << 1` = `0xE`, not `0xF`.  Even for encryption schemes, we can trivially show it isn't true because asymmetric encryption algorithms exist.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Information Security. I never heard of this law, but it sounds like the pipe dream (no pun intended) of all those 3-letter agencies.

Comment: I have heard of this "law", and it has been referenced a few times in answers here over the years. If it's the same thing, the "law" is not a law and faulty in its understanding of cryptography.

Comment: I just googled "digital fortress all encryption can be broken" and got "bergofsky principle" as the hit.

Comment: Maybe this read - How Does Legislation Affect Digital Footprint - is of interest for you: https://www.internetsociety.org/wp-content/uploads/tutorials/How_Does_Legislation_Affect_Digital_Footprints/presentation_content/external_files/How_Does_Legislation_Affect_Digital_Footprints.pdf

Comment: @overmind wrong type of footprint.

Comment: From [Course Hero](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p7q6q0f/Unbreakable-Susan-couldnt-believe-the-word-hadbeen-uttered-by-a-man-with-twenty/), the Bergofsky Principle "_clearly stated that if a computer tried enough keys, it was mathematically guaranteed to find the right one. A code’s security was not that its pass-key was unfindable but rather that most people didn’t have the time or equipment to try._" Which is sort-of-true, if we're allowed to discount that the heat-death of the universe might happen first.

Comment: Just a tip:  Don't ever take anything from a Dan Brown novel to be based in fact.  Digital Fortress is perhaps the stupidest compilation of nonsense ever published.

Comment: The existence of [information-theoretic secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information-theoretic_security) algorithms such as the one-time pad trivially disproves this "law".

Comment: @Xander why is a stupidest compilation of nonsense instead of, well, a fiction book? i mean it's an interesting for me to think about how to say this is precisely. when there's a story about dragons, no one criticises it as like 'dragons don't exist', but if a book comes up with something like 'bergofsky principle', one might criticise as saying it doesn't exist? hmmmm...perhaps you might say like say game of thrones isn't set in our reality while dan's browns books are. but what about harry potter? it's supposedly in our reality just along side another. hmmm...

Comment: @Xander anyhoo i miss the dan brown plot generator. huhu https://web.archive.org/web/20100219043347/http://www.slate.com/default.aspx?id=2228327

Comment: @BCLC It doesn't just describe a fictional creature. It actually gets a fundamental truth in mathematics wrong. Now, if the book was about some alternate universe with different laws of mathematics, people wouldn't be complaining. To state that a + b = 37 can be truly **reversed** is just... stupid.

Comment: @forest ah ok thanks! indeed people cannot write mathematical fiction. you can have another universe with different biology or physics because you change the physical universe or the bodies of sentient beings or whatever but mathematics is just constant. what exactly is the mathematical error please?

Comment: @BCLC The mathematics error is the assumption that all operations are reversible, where "reversible" means, given the output of a function, you can always determine the original input. I described the details in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no such law, and the claim itself is false.**

In a cryptography, there are irreversible operations such as [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), which destroys information by taking two inputs but having only one output. There are also reversible operations, such as [NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation), which takes one input and gives one output. It would be necessary to design a special, reversible version of otherwise irreversible operations. An example is [CCNOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate), which takes three inputs and has three outputs. If this is done, *and* all the outputs are preserved, then indeed secret cryptography would become impossible.

> This is a computer science law that states for the purposes of encryption that all operations on a computer can be reversed which means that in theory all codes can be cracked.

Counterexample: I have chosen two secret numbers *a* and *b* such that a + b = 37. Try to reverse it.

For a cryptographic counterexample, consider the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) (OTP). It is perfectly secret because, given some ciphertext, the probability that it is the encryption of a given plaintext message is exactly equal to the probability that it is the encryption of another plaintext message. This statement holds true for *all possible plaintexts and ciphertexts*, without exception, when using a uniformly random key. The OTP theorem states that, if plaintext *p* is a variable with any distribution over {0,1}<sup>n</sup> and *k* is a uniform random variable over {0,1}<sup>n</sup>, then the ciphertext c = p ⊕ k is a uniform random variable over {0,1}<sup>n</sup>.

<sub>This answer only describes logical reversibility and not thermodynamic reversibility, which is another subject entirely.</sub>

Comment: Hey thanks to all for your answers. I didn't really think its a law anymore than I think Moore's Law is an actual law. Its just an observation that puts us in a pigeonhole to keep doubling our computational prowess. I got ran off physics stack exchange where no one could helpIm gladf i found yall.  Awesome. Thanks for the free education.